# Distance between colors in AnLab color space

Tags: c++, colors, color-space

I want to write a program that will calculate a *deltaE* (distance between colors) in *AnLab* color space.

The formula is here: [Click Here](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cdpi%7B150%7D&space;%5CDelta&space;E_%7BAn%7D=40%5Csqrt%7B0.23(%5CDelta&space;V_%7BY%7D)%5E%7B2%7D+%5CDelta&space;(V_%7BX%7D-V_%7BY%7D)%5E%7B2%7D+0.4%5CDelta&space;(V_%7BZ%7D-V_%7BY%7D)%5E%7B2%7D%7D), where deltaVy is a difference between brightness coordinates and delta(Vx-Vy) and delta(Vz-Vy) are differences between color coordinates.

So,
1. How to calulate deltaVx, deltaVy, deltaVz?
2. Maybe someone has some more information about this color space. I would appreciate.

I made so far a calculation from RGB to XYZ but got stuck in deltaVx,Vy,Vz calculations.

**EDIT:**
After some searching i found that deltaVx,Vy,Vz comes from adding shrinking coordinates to XYZ. But after all calculations i don't know why the distance is wrong (very big value). I edited my code too, so now it has implemented formulas. Also for testing purpose i've put very similar colors (now deltaE should be small value but something is wrong).

Edited code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class colorRGB
{
public:
    double R1, G1, B1;  // RGB colors
    double X, Y, Z; // vectors
    double Vx, Vy, Vz;
    double L, a, b;
    colorRGB(double R, double G, double B) //Make new color
    {
        this->R1 = R;
        this->G1 = G;
        this->B1 = B;   
    } 
    void wypisz()
    {
        cout << "X: " << X << " " << "Y: " << Y << " " << "Z: " << Z << endl;
        cout << "Vx: " << Vx << " Vy: " << Vy << " Vz: " << Vz << endl;
        cout << "L: " << L << " a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }
    void calcLab(double pVx, double pVy, double pVz) // calulate L*ab
    {
        L = 9.2*(pVy);
        a = 40 * (pVx - pVy);
        b = 16 * (pVy - pVz);
    }
    void RGBtoXYZ()
    {
        double R = R1 / 255; // R from 0 to 255 etc.
        double G = G1 / 255; 
        double B = B1 / 255;

        if (R > 0.04045) { // R to X
            R = (R + 0.055) / 1.055;
            R = pow(R, 2.4);
        }
        else R = R / 12.92;

        if (G > 0.04045) { // G to Y
            G = (G + 0.055) / 1.055;
            G = pow(G, 2.4);
        }
        else   G = G / 12.92;

        if (B > 0.04045) { // B to Z
            B = (B + 0.055) / 1.055;
            B = pow(B, 2.4);
        }
        else B = B / 12.92;

        R = R * 100;
        G = G * 100;
        B = B * 100;

        //Illuminant = D65
        X = (R * 0.4124) + (G * 0.3576) + (B * 0.1805);
        Y = (R * 0.2126) + (G * 0.7152) + (B * 0.0722);
        Z = (R * 0.0193) + (G * 0.1192) + (B * 0.9505);

        X = X - Y; // subtract from X and Z (prepare variables to further calculations)
        Z = Z - Y;

        Vx = X + 0.4124 + 0.3576 + 0.1805; // add shrinking coordinates
        Vy = Y + 0.2126 + 0.7152 + 0.0722;
        Vz = Z + 0.0193 + 0.1192 + 0.9505;

        calcLab(Vx, Vy, Vz); 

    }
};

void calcDeltaVar(colorRGB *color1, colorRGB *color2) {
    int x = 0;
    double dE;
    double ins;
    double dVy = color1->Vy - color2->Vy;
    double dVxVy = color1->Vx - color2->Vy;
    double dVzVy = color1->Vz - color2->Vy;

    ins = 0.23*(pow(dVy, 2)) + pow(dVxVy, 2) + 0.4*(pow(dVzVy, 2));
    dE = 40 * (sqrt(ins));
    x++;
    cout << "Delta Ean for pair " << x << " is: " << dE << endl;

};



int main()
{
    colorRGB rgb(255.0, 255.0, 255.0);
    colorRGB rgb1(254.0, 254.0, 254.0);

    rgb.RGBtoXYZ();
    rgb.wypisz();

    rgb1.RGBtoXYZ();
    rgb1.wypisz();

    calcDeltaVar(&rgb, &rgb1);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: 1. How to calulate deltaVx, deltaVy, deltaVz? 2. Maybe someone has some more information about this color space. I would appreciate.

Comment: anyone? please help!